# Supervisord config changes not recognized after reread/update

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, ubuntu-16.04, supervisord

having some issues with using supervisord to run processes on an ubuntu machine.

When I make changes to the config file, I've tried the recommended method of `reread` and then `update` to get the changes and then restarting the process. But this doesn't do anything. The process remains in it's pre-configuration state. It's only when I run `supervisorctl reload` that the changes actually take effect

Of the process group, there are several that ideally need 100% uptime or close to it so running `supervisorctl reload` every time I want to change something is not a feasible option. Is this a known bug? Most of the solutions I've come across on SO have recommend using `reload` as a last resort... which obviously is not an option for me.

FWIW, `reread` and `update` have worked fine on a similar CentOS machine..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try running `supervisorctl update` by itself. `reread` only pulls in changes without restarting any processes. It could be that by calling that first, `supervisorctl` doesn't see any change and therefore no need to restart processes when you run `update`.

Comment: That was it!! Thank you. Most of the documentation recommends `reread` AND then `update`, but I can't believe I never tried just running `update`..